# How do to explicitly define the query used in subqueryload_all?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, relationships

I'm using subqueryload/subqueryload_all pretty heavily, and I've run into the edge case where I tend to need to very explicitly define the query that is used during the subqueryload.  For example I have a situation where I have posts and comments.  My query looks something like this:

```
posts_q = db.query(Post).options(subqueryload(Post.comments))
```

As you can see, I'm loading each Post's comments.  The problem is that I don't want all of the posts' comments, I need to also take into account a deleted field, and they need to be ordered by create time descending.  The only way I have observed this being done, is by adding options to the `relationship()` declaration between posts and comments.  I would prefer not to do this, b/c it means that that relationship cannot be reused everywhere after that, as I have other places in the app where those constraints may not apply.

What I would love to do, is explicitly define the query that subqueryload/subqueryload_all uses to load the posts' comments. I read about DisjointedEagerLoading [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/DisjointEagerLoading), and it looks like I could simply define a special function that takes in the base query, and a query to load the specified relationship.  Is this a good route to take for this situation?  Anyone ever run into this edge case before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem and it took my some time to realize that this is an issue by design. When you say `Post.comments` then you refer to the relationship that says "these are all the comments of that post". However, now you want to filter them. If you'd now specify that condition somewhere on `subqueryload` then you are essentially loading only a subset of values into `Post.comments`. Thus, there will be values missing. Essentially you have a faulty representation of your data in the model.

The question here is how to approach this then, because you obviously need this value *somewhere*. The way I go is building the subquery myself and then specify special conditions there. That means you get two objects back: The list of posts and the list of comments. That is not a pretty solution, but at least it is not displaying data in a wrong way. If you were to access `Post.comments` for some reason, you can safely assume it contains all posts.

But there is room for improvement: You might want to have this attached to your class so you don't carry around two variables. The easy way might be to define a second relationship, e.g. `published_comments` which specifies extra parameters. You could then also control that no-one writes to it, e.g. with [attribute events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents). In these events you could, instead of forbidding manipulation, handle how manipulation is allowed. The only problem might be when updates happen, e.g. when you add a comment to `Post.comments` then `published_comments` won't be updated automatically because they are not aware of each other. Again, I'd take events for this if this is a required feature (but with the above ugly solution you would not have that either).

As a last, hybrid, solution you could take the first approach and then just assign those values to your object, e.g. `Post.deleted_comments = deleted_comments`.

The thing to keep in mind here is that it is generally not a clever idea to manipulate the query the ORM makes as this could lead to problems later on. I have taken this approach and manipulated the queries (with [`contains_eager`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager) this is easily possible) but it has created problems on some points (while generally being functional) so I dropped that approach.

Comment: Yah interesting explanation of the situation.  I eventually just chose to go the `contains_eager` route.  Thanks for the additional suggestion of multiple relationships, I had thought about it before, but was unsure about it. You pointed out the main pitfalls of doing that way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you can define multiple relationships between `Post`s and `Comment`s:

```
class Post(...):
    active_comments = relationship(Comment,
         primary_join=and_(Comment.post_id==Post.post_id, Comment.deleted=False),
         order_by=Comment.created.desc())
```

Then you should be able to subqueryload by that relationship:

```
posts_q = db.query(Post).options(subqueryload(Post.active_comments))
```

You can still use the existing `.comments` relationship elsewhere.